# Is there a method to vectorize applying a function to every element of a Tensor

Tags: vectorization, pytorch

I want to implement an update rule in an optimization procedure. I wanted to vectorize it using pytorch functions to improve time complexity. Possibly run on a GPU.

The update rule is like

```
u[i][j] = multiplier*NORM(Q.column(i)-Q.column(j))
```

I have tried to write a simple nested loop for its execution but it seems to be absymally slow.

```
def u_vector(Q,parameters):
    u=torch.zeros(Q.shape[0],Q.shape[0],requires_grad=False)
    for i in range(Q.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i+1,Q.shape[1]):
            u[i][j]=0.5*(torch.norm(Q[:,i]-Q[:,j]))*parameters['gamma']
            u[j][i]=u[i][j]
    return u
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility using indexing to compute all the differences and norms at once. You'll need to test to see if it's faster on your hardware.

```
def u_vector(Q,parameters):
    cols = Q.shape[1]
    # equivalent to generating a meshgrid
    c1 = [i for i in range(cols) for _ in range(cols)]
    c2 = [i for _ in range(cols) for i in range(cols)]
    return 0.5 * torch.norm(Q[:,c1] - Q[:,c2], dim=0).reshape(cols, cols) * parameters['gamma']
```

---

*Disclaimer*.  It's kind of strange that you use `Q.shape[0]` to define the shape of `u` and range of indices since all your indexing is used to access columns of `Q`.
The code provided above only matches your function if `Q` is square (also, yours will crash due to invalid index if `Q` has more columns than rows). If you want something which produces the exact same output as yours then the following will work. The only difference between this and the previous version is that it pads with zeros when `Q.shape[0] > Q.shape[1]`.

```
def u_vector(Q,parameters):
    rows, cols = Q.shape[0], Q.shape[1]
    c1 = [i for i in range(cols) for _ in range(cols)]
    c2 = [i for _ in range(cols) for i in range(cols)]
    u = 0.5 * torch.norm(Q[:,c1] - Q[:,c2], dim=0).reshape(cols, cols) * parameters['gamma']
    return torch.nn.functional.pad(u, (0, rows-cols, 0, rows-cols), 'constant', 0)
```

Also observe that this will run on the GPU if `Q` is on the GPU.